# how to setting up AppDelegate for push notification in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to setup a push notification system for my application. I have a server and a developer license to setup the push notification service.

I am currently running my app in Swift4 Xcode 9

here are my questions :

1_ is that possible that I set the title and body of notification massage ??

2_ what is the func of receiving massage ? I'm using `didReceiveRemoteNotification`  but this is called when I touch the notification I need a func which is called before showing notification that I can set my massage on it

3_ I'm generating device token in appDelegate and also in my login page for my server which are different from each other. this is not correct right ?

this is my app delegate :

```
          func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
                // Override point for customization after application launch.

                print("lunch",launchOptions?.description,launchOptions?.first)

                 application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                FirebaseApp.configure()
                GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyAXGsvzqyN3ArpWuycvQ5GS5weLtptWt14")

                UserDefaults.standard.set(["fa_IR"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


                  registerForPushNotifications()
                return true
            }


       func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {

            print("test : ",messaging.apnsToken)
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

            print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
            print()
           // completionHandler(.newData)

        }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        print("userInfo : ",userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == .active {
            print("active")
            //write your code here when app is in foreground
        } else {
            print("inactive")

            //write your code here for other state
        }
    }


   func getNotificationSettings() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        } else {


        }
    }


    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
                (granted, error) in
                print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
                guard granted else { return }
                self.getNotificationSettings()
            }
        } else {

            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound, .badge], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()


           // self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can manage the content of notification by sending an appropriate payload in the notification. Sending the payload in the following pattern would show title and body in the notification

> ```
> {
>         "aps" : {
>             "alert" : {
>                 "title" : "Game Request",
>                 "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
>             },
>             "badge" : 5
>         } 
> }
> ```

2. Display the notification is handled by the system depending upon the app state. If the app is the foreground state you will get the call in the `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, otherwise, the system handles the displaying part and get control in the app when the user taps on the notification.

**You cannot edit the content of notification from the app side.**

3. According to the document

> APNs can issue a new device token for a variety of reasons:
>
> User installs your app on a new device
>
> User restores device from a backup
>
> User reinstalls the operating system
>
> Other system-defined events

So its recommended requesting device token at launch time.

You can send the token in login page rather than requesting a new token in the login.

Comment: I'm using didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken func that generates token and also using InstanceID.instanceID().token()  for generate token.these two are generating different

Comment: @M0TRIX I don't know why you are using InstanceID.instanceID().token(), since these are 2 different method obviously you will get 2 tokens.  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken returns the token that is registered with APNS, which should be used for sending push.